# Eclipse: Hide paths in the "Open resource" dialog

Tags: eclipse

Is there any way to define what the "Open Resource" dialog in Eclipse should show?

If you work with svn you don't want the *.svn files to show up. (I know there is a fix out for this one but does there exist a more general one?)

Answer (score 13):

At the top-right corner of the "Open Resource" there is a small blue arrow.
Click it and "Select Working Set".
Create a new working set as required to include what you need

Answer (score 3):

You could mark the files as 'derived', though depending on their directory structure it could be time-consuming.  See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2632419/292728).