# Eclipse (Galileo) : How to ignore .svn-base files or *.svn folder in Open Resource dialog?

Tags: eclipse, svn, resources

I am using TortoiseSVN client. I do not want to see SVN client files in Open resource dialog window. Is there any way to ignore particular folder name or file name ?

I have checked following links, There are suggesting to create working set.I am not happy with that because, i have  browse down to each package and select the required resource. Is there any other way?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233220?sort=oldest#sort-top
[Eclipse :: Hide .svn files in Open Resource dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569032/eclipse-hide-svn-files-in-open-resource-dialog)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am using the [Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/) plugin as an SVN client. It hides the SVN client files. As much as I know, the [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) also solves this problem.

My suggestion is to use any of these plugins as an SVN client, it will solve the problem. My preference is the Subversive, but here you can find other opinions also: [What are the pros and cons of the SVN plugins for Eclipse, Subclipse and Subversive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61320/svn-plugins-for-eclipse-subclipse-vs-subversive#61328)