# How to filter *.class in Open Resource dialog (Ctrl+Shift+R)?

Tags: eclipse, grails, groovy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I hide .class files from the Open Resource dialog in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632419/how-do-i-hide-class-files-from-the-open-resource-dialog-in-eclipse)

A direct question:

How to filter `*.class` in Open Resource dialog (Ctrl+Shift+R) in Eclipse ?

---

**UPDATE:**

Explain better: I need to HIDE all `*.class` files...I'm programing in groovy/grails. So, when I do Ctrl+Shift+R to open Order.groovy (for example), I see Order.class too...and sometimes I open the wrong file.

My Eclipse is the STS ([Spring Tool Suite](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a naive answer, but it does what you asked for. But probably not what you are after...

How about typing `*.class` in the Ctrl+Shift+R dialog?

There's one catch with this approach. Typically you won't see the `.class` files there, because they are so called derived resources (generated by Eclipse in compilation process from your `.java` files). But you can make the Ctrl+Shift+R dialog show them too by checking the option "Show derived resources" in the configuration menu there:
[image: Eclipse screenshot]

Comment: I guess classes are not consider derived, because here I see them in the resource dialog even though the 'show derived classes' is unchecked.

Comment: That's strange, because they do disappear if I uncheck 'derived' on my computer.

Comment: Odd. It might be because mine are generated by maven/ant, and not the eclipse compiler. But in fact some of them should be generated by eclipse

Comment: anyway, I think it is unchecked by default, so perhaps his case is the same as mine..

Comment: It was unchecked in my Eclipse too.

Comment: note the he wants to hide them, not show them (at least this is how I understand the question)

Comment: That's funny. I understood he wants to focus only `.class` files. But now I see your point and you are probably right in your interpretation. That would make sense to hide all the `class` files junk.

Comment: I need to HIDE *.class... I've updated the question...by the way, thanks a lot!

Comment: This is close - you want to hide derived files. But you need to right-click on the 'target' folder and go to Properties and check the checkbox indicating it's derived.

Comment: Man! It works! I just mark "derived" in checkbox (in folder properties) and works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Doesn't work for multi module maven eclipse projects

Answer (score 6):

Not possible, to my knowledge.

But that should rarely be a problem - you usually use this dialog if you know the name of the resource, and they should rarely coincide with class names.

And if you want to open .java files, just use `CTRL + SHIFT + T`

Answer (score 1):

By creating a `working set` selecting only your class folders. It's not a ready made solution, but easy to do with few projects.