# Open Type/Resource in Eclipse restricted to particular directory

Tags: eclipse

When I use Open Type / Open Resource dialog in Eclipse and start typing the resource name I get the results from the entire project rather than from the source directories I specified in the project configuration. To be more specific - WEB-INF/classes binary directory is a part of my project but I do not want the files from that directory to appear in the Open Resource dialog results. Is there any way to restrict it?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632419/how-do-i-hide-class-files-from-the-open-resource-dialog-in-eclipse

Comment: @Balaswamy, You are right, I did not notice that one. It solved my problem, thanks.

Comment: u r welcome sometime it happens

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I hide .class files from the Open Resource dialog in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632419/how-do-i-hide-class-files-from-the-open-resource-dialog-in-eclipse)