# How do I hide .java files from the Open Resource dialog in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

In an IDEal world I should be able to filter by pattern or at least file extension.
I never want to open .java files in Open Resource, there's a separate window called Open Type for that.

I saw this, but it's not a general solution: [How do I hide .class files from the Open Resource dialog in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632419/how-do-i-hide-class-files-from-the-open-resource-dialog-in-eclipse)
I cannot simply mark the .java files as derived, because they're not!

Comment: Did you mean .class files?

Comment: @Kocko - the question you referenced is the same as the one the OP has referenced

Comment: @sp00m Nope, .java I want; that's why I referenced the .class question (so that you see, I'm aware of that).

Answer (score 0):

Go to

Project -> Properties -> Resource -> Resource Filters -> Add

There you select: Exclude All, Folders, All Children (recursive)

Name Matches: .java

That should do the trick.

regards, kayz

Comment: Exclude All, Files, All Children (recursive), *.java [optionally case sensitive, maybe it's faster].

Comment: It successfully hides all the java files, even from my source folders, so all I have is the plain package structure without the ability to edit any Java code. Maybe I forgot to mention that it's a Java project. So it reaches the goal, but pointless.

Answer (score 0):

What worked great for me is

1. Open the `Open Resource` dialog (`Ctrl + Shift + R`, or `Navigate > Open Resource`)
2. Click the kebab menu (the three dots icon, top right of that dialog)
3. Click on the `Select Working Set`
4. Select all checkboxes under the `Selected Working Sets`
5. Click on the `OK` button
6. Et voila - now I see only 1 match instead of 8 as