# How to exclude some project/path in Eclipse Open Resource result list?

Tags: eclipse

This is a maven project and there is a parent project parent and some child modules, e.g. foo, bar.

```
<modules>
    <module>foo</module>
    <module>bar</module>
    ...
</modules>
```

Now in **eclipse** I want to search a file, e.g. FooService.java, I enter ctrl + shift + R simultaneously, open `Open Resource`  window, but there are many FooService, e.g

```
parent/foo/src/main/java/com/foo/service/
foo/src/main/java/com/foo/service/
```

now I want to exclude parent option How to configure it in Eclipse?

Comment: This same issue was causing a problem for me.  I would open a *Test.java file from the parent option, and the Run As > Junit context menu option didn't exist.  When I opened the *Test.java file from the non-parent option eclipse recognized it better and provided the Run As > Junit test menu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you click the small down arrow (looks like a triangle) at the top right of the Open Resource dialog you can restrict the search to a particular Working Set.

Clicking 'Select Working Set' will allow you to create a new working set if you do not have a suitable existing Working Set.

Answer (score 6):

On Eclipse Neon, (on click on the triangle) there is an Option in the Dialog to "Filter Duplicated Resources". This works perfect with the Maven Parent / Module Situation.

Comment: Works perfectly !

Comment: Another solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11251249/1568658 , which could also ignore `.class` files.